# FileUpload (Apache Commons) and Java POI IOException: Unable to read entire header

Tags: java, apache-poi, multipart, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm trying to user Apache Commons Streaming API to get the information from an excel spreadsheet. I keep on getting the following error:

```
    SEVERE: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:908)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.getItemIterator(ServletFileUpload.java:148)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.processRequest(ReportServlet.java:54)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.doPost(ReportServlet.java:178)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

INFO: Reports
INFO: Form field upload_report_btnwith valueUpload Report detected
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:908)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.getItemIterator(ServletFileUpload.java:148)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.processRequest(ReportServlet.java:54)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.doPost(ReportServlet.java:178)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:908)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.getItemIterator(ServletFileUpload.java:148)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.processRequest(ReportServlet.java:54)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.doPost(ReportServlet.java:178)
    at eBooks.controller.ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is the code of ReportServlet that process the information:

```
package eBooks.controller;

/**
 * @author L10
 */

import eBooks.business.Account;
import eBooks.business.Report;
import eBooks.business.User;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;



public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet
{

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        try 
        {
            // Check that we have a file upload request
            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

            //Create a new file upload Handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();


            //Parse the request
            FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);                    

            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();

                        if(item.isFormField())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Form field " + name + "with value" + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected" );                            
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(stream);               
                            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
                            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                            System.out.println(wb.getSheetName(0));

                            //  session
                            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

                            //Define define values obatained from the document

                            Report report = new Report();
                            User user = new User();
                            Account account = new Account();                    

                            int reportType = report.getReportType();

                            String emailAddress = user.getEmailAddress();
                            String account_id = account.getAccount_id();
                            String accountName = account.getAccountName();
                            String userRole = user.getUserRole();

                            String reportName = report.getReportName(); // is the spreadsheet Name
                            String reportDate = report.getReportDate(); // is the period on the report

                            double totalUS = report.getMonthTotalUS();
                            double totalEUR = report.getMonthTotalEUR();
                            double grandTotal = report.getMonthGrandTotal();

                            double averagePrice = report.getAverageSalePrice();

                            int totalUnitsSold = report.getTotalUnitsSold();
                            double monthlyAverageUnitsSold = report.getMonthlyAverageUnitsSold();
                            double dailyAverageUnitsSold = report.getDailyAverageUnitsSold();

                            int totalUnitsRefunded = report.getTotalUnitsRefunded();
                            double monthlyAverageUnitsRefunded = report.getMonthlyAverageUnitsRefunded();
                            double dailyAverageUnitsRefuded = report.getDailyAverageUnitsRefuded();

                            double monthlyAverageRoyalties = report.getMonthlyAverageRoyalties();

                            // set values for the user, account & report objects

                            report.setReportType(reportType);

                            user.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
                            account.setAccount_id(account_id);
                            account.setAccountName(accountName);
                            user.setUserRole(userRole);

                            report.setReportName(reportName); // is the spreadsheet Name
                            report.setReportDate(reportDate); // is the period on the report

                            report.setMonthTotalUS(totalUS);
                            report.setMonthTotalEUR(totalEUR);
                            report.setMonthGrandTotal(grandTotal);

                            report.setAverageSalePrice(averagePrice);

                            report.setTotalUnitsSold(totalUnitsSold);
                            report.setMonthlyAverageUnitsSold(monthlyAverageUnitsSold);
                            report.setDailyAverageUnitsSold(dailyAverageUnitsSold);

                            report.setTotalUnitsRefunded(totalUnitsRefunded);
                            report.setMonthlyAverageUnitsRefunded(monthlyAverageUnitsRefunded);
                            report.setDailyAverageUnitsRefuded(dailyAverageUnitsRefuded);

                            report.setMonthlyAverageRoyalties(monthlyAverageRoyalties);


                        // TODO: Add information to the database

                            // set Session for the user, account & report
                            session.setAttribute("User", user);
                            session.setAttribute("Account", account);
                            session.setAttribute("Report", report);                  

                            Cookie emailCookie = new Cookie("emailCookie", emailAddress);
                            emailCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365*2);
                            emailCookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(emailCookie);

                            String url = "/WEB-INF/view/Dashboard.jsp";
                            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
                            dispatcher.forward(request, response);


                        }
            }

        }catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doPost(request, response);

    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


}
```

This how my form looks:

```
<form action="ReportServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file"/> 
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload Report" name="upload_report_btn" />
                </form>
```

I'm using glassfish. Any ideas why I keep on getting this message?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you seem to be assuming that the first and only multipart object arriving will be the spreadsheet file.  The form itself will be present as well.  The clue is the message

```
Unable to read entire header; 13 bytes read; expected 512 bytes
```

Notice, the form's uploaded value is `Upload Report`, which happens to be 13 bytes long.

You could have easily seen this if you used a browser-based debugging tool such as Firebug or Fiddler.  One of these tools should be in your tool-set.

Comment: You need to examine what is being sent from the browser to determine where the problem is.  Use FireBug, Fiddler or Wireshark to examine the data stream.